# Обработка JTabbedPane после добавления

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте. У меня есть проект, где я использую JTabbedPane. Я хочу обрабатывать событие, когда в него добавляется новая вкладка. Я использовал ContainerListener(). Но получается, что когда я добавляю несколько вкладок в цикле, то для каждого вызывается listener, но физически они ещё не добавлены, соответственно я не могу получить их содержимое.
Как выполнять обработку после того, как вкладка полностью добавилась на панель.

Вызов добавления вкладок

```
    matchParseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                final String url = teamsIds.get(i);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        secondWebBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
                        System.out.println(secondWebBrowser
                                .navigate("http://www.flashscore.com/match/" + url + "/#h2h;overall"));
                        tabbedPane.addTab("New Tab", secondWebBrowser);
                    }
                });
```

Слушатели

```
 tabbedPane.addContainerListener(new ContainerListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentRemoved(ContainerEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
            //webBrowser.`
            System.out.println("added");
            if (tabbedPane.getComponentAt(1) instanceof JWebBrowser) {
                System.out.println(secondWebBrowser.getHTMLContent());
            }

        }
    });
```

SecondWebBrowser возвращает null, потому что все 5 вкладок добавляются после завершения цикла одновременно.